Marker is not appear in google map in js
I am working cordova application which is released to play store and appstore, In my application goggle map is used it was working proper before. but now, suddenly, map markers are not showing. It was a big problem for user so i checked the console where I didn't get any error but I got this warning:

i.e google.maps.Marker is deprecated instead of that use google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement

I even tried by using the above solution but the issue is not resolved, it was throwing the error as below

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AdvancedMarkerElement')

I was struck don't know what to do. Can you give me any solution regarding this?

Please give us some code for us to help you. We cannot help what we do not know.

Before my code as ==>
var marker = new google.maps.Markers({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
map: map,
icon: 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|' + color
});
marker.setMap(map);
After the waring I changed the code as ==>
var marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
map: map,
icon: 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|' + color
});
marker.setMap(map);

You most probably didn't add the callback that GoogleMaps needs.
There were 2 updates to Google Maps
1- You need to add a callback to a global function adding &callback=myGlobalFunction to your script link, that's what you most probably missed. Just declare
 function myGlobalFunction(){
      console.log('Gmaps is happy');
 }

2- Then they moved to a new JS base and you need to use AdvancedMarkerElement but they don't plan on removing support for the old lib, so you can keep your old code it seems
